# Center absolute positioned images of unknown sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

In my `AngularJS` project I have a list of images of unknown sizes, what I want is to have the images centered horizontally inside the `div class="slideshow">`. this could be done with having `slideshow` style to `text-align:center` and then remove the hidden imaged with `ng-if`, however I want to have the images fade from one to the other which wouldn't happen with `ng-if`.

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michaeltotkorsgaard/L56rdqLp/6/) with what I have. In the example I've used `LoremPixel` with predefined sizes, in my application these sizes are unknown

I hope someone out there knows a trick ;-)

Comment: Images are to be centred on the entire page or centred in the _slideshow_ div?

Comment: @Tigger: oh yea,might be good to know. It should be centered in the `<div class="slideshow">`

Comment: vertical center or horizontal?

Comment: @ManojLodhi: horizontal ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this css in your style

```
.slideshow img {width: 100%; opacity: 0;}
```

.slideshow .images {float:left; width:100;}

Comment: Based on your suggestion I chaged the code to this, which works. Thanks ^^ https://jsfiddle.net/michaeltotkorsgaard/L56rdqLp/22/

Comment: .slideshow {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border: 1px solid rgba(79, 132, 148, 0.5);
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: table;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 50%;
}  .slideshow img.active {
    max-height: none;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s ease 0s;
}.slideshow img {
    max-height: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
}      add this css

Answer (score 0):

Nothing fancy required, just set the image as the background to the div like so:

```
<div id="slideshow" style="margin:auto;width:50%;height:350px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background-color:#888;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/')">
```

Then you can update with Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('slideshow').style.backgroundImage = 'urlOfNewImage';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**CSS**

```
 .slideshow .images {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .slideshow img {
        position: relative;
        top: 5px;
        top: 0px;
        max-height: calc(100% - 10px);
        max-width: calc(100% - 10px);
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 1s ease;
    }
```

You can check the jsFiddle here

https://jsfiddle.net/L56rdqLp/20/

Answer (score 0):

If someone want to fade the images in place, floating would not work. (There were no examples with fading)

You need to position your elements with: `position: absolute;`

But then, it is not that straight forward to center the images with this one.

1. As suggested you could do this with in a (div) holder and setting a background image.

   ```
   div {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: url(".."); background-size: cover}
   ```

A second option would be this one:

```
display: block;
position: absolute;
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
```

Here is a working example with (working and fading code of yours..)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', "$interval", function(scope, $interval) {
  scope.setImage = function (slide) {
      scope.slideshow.forEach(function(item) {item._active = false;});
      slide._active = true;
  };
  scope.slideshow = [
                {
                    src: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/',
                    _active: true
                },
                {
                    src: 'http://lorempixel.com/500/400/',
                    _active: false
                },
                {
                    src: 'http://lorempixel.com/100/800/',
                    _active: false
                }
            ]
            
  $interval(function(){
  //console.log("test");
            var index = -1
            for(var i = 0; i < scope.slideshow.length; i++){
                if(scope.slideshow[i]._active){
                    // console.info('active : ', scope.slideshow[i])
                    if(!scope.slideshow[i]._time){
                        scope.slideshow[i]._time = new Date()
                    }
                    var oldTime = moment(scope.slideshow[i]._time),
                        now = moment()

                    // console.info(now.diff(oldTime, 'seconds'))
                    if(now.diff(oldTime, 'seconds') > 5){
                        index = i + 1
                    }
                }
            }

            if(index > -1){
                if(index >= scope.slideshow.length){
                    index = 0
                }

                scope.setImage(scope.slideshow[index])
            }
        }, 1000)
}])
```

```css
.slideshow {
        display: block;
        height: 350px;
        width: 50%;
        border: 1px solid rgba(79,132,148,.5);
        border-radius: 3px;
        background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
        padding: 5px;
        margin: auto;
    }
        .slideshow .images {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
            .slideshow img {
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                transform-origin: 50% 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                //max-height: calc(100%-10px);
                //max-width: calc(100%-10px);
                opacity: 0;
                transition: opacity 1s ease;
            }
            .slideshow img.active {
                opacity: 1;
                transition: opacity 1s ease;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <section class="slideshow">
        <div class="images">
            <img ng-repeat="img in slideshow track by $index"
                    src="{{ img.src }}"
                    ng-class="img._active ? 'active' : ''" />
        </div>
    </section>
</div>

</div>
```